# How to set app/server/Rack-wide timezone in Sinatra/Rack apps?

Tags: ruby, timezone, sinatra, rack

Is there a way to set the timezone for the entire Rack stack?

Ideally, I'd like one setting that can propagate to all middleware components, up to Sinatra, or whatever may be sitting on the front end of stack. Is the any way to do this? Bonus points for a solution that also works on Heroku.

Comment: How is this a programming question?  Perhaps you should ask on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: The question is how to change the time zone setting programmatically, from Ruby or from within the app?

Answer (score 3):

Heroku uses UTC by default.

To change it you may be able to do `heroku config:add TZ="Europe/Athens"`

Though, this only addresses Heroku, the idea behind it (setting your local time on a server) should work just as well.